# If $G \cong H \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, show that $G$ contains an element $a$ of order $2$ with the property that $ag = ga$ for all $g \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have so far that there is one element in $H \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with order two which commutes with everything else in that group, namely $(e_H, 1)$. This is presuming that $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a group under addition.

However, I can't see why this means that $G$ must also contain an element with the same property. Should this be the next stage of my proof or am I heading in the wrong direction?

Comment: If you have an isomorphism, something will map to $(e_H,1)$, then say the isomorphism is called $f$, if $f(ga)=f(ag)$ then $ga=ag$ as $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a correct answer to my own question.

If $\phi: G \rightarrow H \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is the isomorphism and $(e_H, 1) \in \mathbb{Z}_2 $ has order $2$, then $\phi(a) = (e_H, 1)$ for some $a$ in $G$. Then $\phi(a^2) = (e_H,0)$ which means that $a^2 = e_G$ since the kernel must contain only $e_G$. Then $a$ must have order $2$.

Secondly take any $g \in G$. I have $\phi(ag) = (e_H,1)(h,n) = (h,n)(e_H,1) = \phi(ga)$ for some $h \in H$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_2$, since the identity commutes with everything and the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is commutative. Then since $\phi$ is injective, this must mean that $ag$ = $ga$.